# how to remove spaces, special characters and numbers in one oracle sql statement

Tags: sql, oracle

how to remove spaces, special characters and numbers in one oracle sql statement

**EDIT**

tried so far:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(NAME ,'[^[:alnum:]'' '']', NULL) FROM table
```

and

```
SELECT translate(NAME,'[0-9]-/^%#-$&&!_. ','[0-9]') last_names FROM table
```

Comment: Please have a look at [ask] and [help/on-topic] before posting a question

Comment: Why not google? Use this for reference [Regexp_replace](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm)

Comment: What exactly do you consider a "special character"?

Comment: @Aleksej : if the columns contain this charcters -/^%#-$&&!_.  spaces numbers 0-9

Comment: SO is not intended to answer questions like "how to do this?"; you should first do some search, try some code and then, if you have a problem on your code, feel free to post it here, trying to build a [mcve].

Comment: Ya i have tried but this code is not serving the purpose, SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(NAME ,'[^[:alnum:]'' '']', NULL) FROM table

Comment: and other what i tried is 
SELECT translate(NAME,'[0-9]-/^%#-$&&!_. ','[0-9]') last_names FROM table

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to delete all the characters different from a letter, you can try the following:

```
select regexp_replace('admin1 xxx', '[^[:alpha:]]', null)
from dual;
```

Comment: Why not? what do you need to get from the string 'asd 123ASD!"£ sdfsf' ?

Comment: i am getting result as asd ASD

Comment: suppose if my column consist of value like 'admin1' then 1 should not be there and if the value is separated by a space ,space should be removed in between the name